# Is the 10:1 prey:predator ratio touted in Zootopia inconsistent with what the film portrays about prey reproduction rates?

Tags: zootopia

Note, this is a slightly different question than can be found [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/131718/zootopia-bunnyburrow-population).

In the movie Zootopia the ratio of prey to predators is empasized in a dramatic scene as 10:1.  In fact, it is a relatively important plot point driving motive within the film.

Gven that in the real world such a ratio is heavily driven by predation and usually fluctuates quite a bit, and given references in the film to population and reproduction of prey species, is that ratio really accurate? Too, how stable would it really be?

I am looking for both in universe and Canon out of universe (e.g. director/write comments/quotes) to support any argument otherwise and if any thought was given to why 10:1 was chosen vs. say 100:1 or even 1000:1. Alternatively, if we completely ignore the laws of biology as we know them, why wouldn't the ratio be only 5:1 or even 1:1?

My suspicion is that the ratio so vocally stated in the film was simply an easily understood 'round number' quote that easily rolls off the tongue. Something along the lines of "We outnumber you 10:1 which gives us the right to do what we want!"  Whereas  "We have exactly the same number of people on our side as yours thus we have a  moral right to do what we want!" doesn't quite sound as impressive.

Some thoughts I have already considered on this:

**Evidence from within the film supporting why the quoted ratio might be inconsistently too low:**

1. As the train is leaving BunnyBurrow we see a sign which includes a real time population counter.  The counter starts at "081435816" which is ~81.4 million rabbits, and is going up rapidly from...5810 to ...5816 in 2 seconds. That is roughly 3 rabbits per second increase.
2. Along with number 1, we learn that Judy has 274 siblings presumably none whom have been eaten by a Canadian Lynx
3. Mr. Big's daughter goes from preparing to get married to having a children within a very short time. Not that it is impossible that she could have been pregnant when she got married (like that never happens to humans :-))  But, I think the implication is that she is going from married, to pregnant, to having children very quickly
4. Technology seems to have removed most non-predatory population pressure items such as food shortages, etc. which might otherwise keep a population in check.

Hence, in the absence of predation, an abundance of food, and obvious fertility, why wouldn't the ratio be much higher than 10:1?

**Possible reasons from within the film why the quoted ratio might be inconsistently too high:**

1. Replacement of predation with other mortality factors such as:

   ```
      a. Obesity (from eating daily sugar popsicles)

      b. Vehicular accidents (from wild driving and police chases)

      c. Modern day job stress (unless you are a sloth :-) ) 

      d. Higher than average Organized crime death (some of the highest
         murder rates in the U.S. were during the gang wars during
         prohibition). 

      e. Caste style poverty for some prey species which may cause less
         access to medical care and shorter lives. An example on the
         predator side of this might be foxes who seem to have
         discrimination in how they expected to behave thus limiting job
         and advancement opportunities.
   ```
2. Outside some specific prey species, voluntary decrease in population growth. We see this in humans who are actually slowing population growth in the absence of predation. Among humans, certain ethnic and religous groups still tend to have higher than average birth rates.  E.g. perhaps bunnys and rodents are the only prey species that still reproduce at such prodigious rates. If others have decreased their birth rates, that may be enough to offset to a 10:1 or less ratio.

Thanks.

Comment: I think that basically, the bunny population was a throwaway joke. I do not think it can be rendered consistent with, well, anything.

Comment: @Adamant. You are very possibly right. However, what didn't seem to be a throwaway joke was the comment about the prey to predator ratio. In fact, that became a relatively important plot point. Hence, I am really curious how that was chosen and why.  Too, Mr. Big's daughter's wedding and subsequent pregnancy while humorous did seem to indicate there are some definite fertility opportunities at work.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is entirely a question about biology that merely happens to be motivated by sci-fi.  It belongs on [Biology.SE], as that is where the experts who can answer it are.

Comment: I reluctantly have to agree. This a "could this really happen" question and thus off-topic, based on our [policy](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/7367/51379) on science questions.

Comment: I read the policy on science questions very carefully as I put this question together. The tag specifically states:  "Any question that is asking for an answer within the context of a fictional universe, even if that question requires real-world science information, is on-topic."  In this case, I am asking based on examples WITHIN the universe itself as to why a particular ratio should be as stated. E.g. I personally think based on the examples show (bunnytown population, rodent reproduction, etc.) that a 10:1 ratio is much lower than it would otherwise be. How is that off-topic?

Comment: Conversely, the policy also states:  "Questions which are explicitly asking for an out-of-universe explanation of the science from a work of science fiction or fantasy should be off-topic."   As worded my question draws upon examples in the film that appear to be internally not-consistent.  If it helps, I can remove the references to the ratio of predator/prey from the real world. But, it does not remove the fact in the film that there IS a ratio quoted which would seem to indicate the laws of biology in Zootopia do work at least something like ours. I.e. prey outnumbers predators.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the 10:1 ratio mentioned is patently ridiculous given the small and micro-small rodent communities. I was thinking about making this an answer, but no one can seriously think that there would be another 1K predators (tiger to weasel) to balance out each 10K small rodent community.

Comment: @Jeeped. That was exactly along the lines of what I was thinking as well.  10:1 simply seems waaay too small. just not consistent with what the rest of the film portrayed about their reproduction rates.

Comment: @beichst Note that they also said 10% in the movie; that would be a 9:1 ratio.  So it's definitely not meant to be exact, more a ballpark estimate.

Comment: @Adamant Bunnyburrow is outside Zootopia, the 10:1 ratio is inside Zootopia

Comment: `unless related directly to a cited work of fiction` - why was this closed?

Comment: The ratio has almost nothing to do with biology, and everything to do with the story portraying a sizeable minority population in a way that actually works.

Comment: In an ecosystem's food pyramid, the biomass of predators at each "trophic level" is commonly estimated as about ten percent of the one below it (https://www.khanacademy.org/science/biology/ecology/intro-to-ecosystems/a/food-chains-food-webs). That is, it takes 10 kg of mice to support 1 kg of cats. As this can be found in many biology textbooks, it may be where the 10:1 ratio of _Zootopia_ originated. Well, it wouldn't apply in-universe to a society where predation had stopped, but _Zootopia_ never explains what its lions eat, so it would be pointless to ask for too much consistency.